# Why does the "dc" command exit(1) when using q(uit)?

Tags: exit-status, dc

```
$ echo "$?"
0
$ echo 'q' | dc || echo "$?"
1
```

Why is using `q` to quit `dc` considered an error?

(The test was run on Ubuntu 20.4.)

Comment: That's probably related to the source code of the `bc` or `dc` package provided by Ubuntu. In my case I have Opensuse and using `q` actually exits with `0` (EXIT_SUCCESS)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `dc` code, go to the bottom of [`dc/eval.c`](https://fossies.org/linux/bc/dc/eval.c?m=h&s=edit-eclipse), line 817:

```
reset_and_exit_quit:
reset_and_exit_fail:
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_default);
    return DC_FAIL;
reset_and_exit_success:
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_default);
    return DC_SUCCESS;
```

the label `reset_and_exit_quit` should come after `reset_and_exit_fail` not before... and that explains why user *Edgar Magallon* [does *not* experience this behavior](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/733264/why-does-the-dc-command-exit1-when-it-finishes#comment1391706_733264) since the folks @ Suse actually have a patch for this: [correct-return-value](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Leap:15.3/bc/bc-dc-correct-return-value.patch?expand=1)
A quick search on [gnu-utils mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/) doesn't return anything related to this issue so if anyone has the time, run a thorough search and if nothing comes up, report it.